# chrome extension- how do i rerun dom manipulation code on original dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, revert

I have a chrome extension with several buttons in the popup, each doing some DOM manipulation (to the current tab) when clicked, using chrome.tabs.executescript().
I want the dom manipulation code to run again for each button, on the ORIGINIAL dom and not the changed one. i.e, after i pressed bt1 in my extension popup the dom changes, and i want to be able to press bt2 to make other changes on the ORIGINAL document, so the changes from bt1 would disappear.

i tried refreshing the page with chrome.tabs.update, using this reloadPage function on my buttons onclick listener:

```
function reloadPage(profleJsonUrl){
    chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
        chrome.tabs.update(tabs[0].id, {url: tabs[0].url},function(){
            personalize(profleJsonUrl);
        });
    });
}

function personalize(profileJsonUrl){
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "jquery.js" }, function () {
            chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {
                code: 'console.log("bt pressed"); var profileJson ="'+profileJsonUrl+'";'
            }, function () {
                chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, { file: "ps1_e.js" });
            });
    });
}
```

but the update callback where my dom manipulation code runs(ps1_e.js) seems to run **BEFORE** the refresh, so the changes are erased. 
How do i fix it? Is there a better a way to achieve remanipuplation of the original dom, perhaps without refreshing?